# What does $$value$$ means and what are the similar constants/reserved words in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I couldn't find anything about this on Google. Can somebody tell me what `ng-model="$$value$$"` means?

Comment: is there a $$value$$ defined by your controller? not as part of angular but as part of controller implementation?

Comment: it was part of a template partial in which it compiles the value from a dynamic form's parent scope.

Comment: I've adjusted the question to avoid the request for a documentation reference, as 'requests for third party resources' are off-topic here (I'm guessing that's the reason for the close vote). I'm sure if someone can answer this, they will add a link if one exists.

Comment: hi halfer wasnt aware of that policy, thanks for correcting.

Comment: and where is that template coming from? which framework

Comment: No worries @YajeDev, have a read [of this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) when you get a mo. Btw, to ping someone here, use their @ handle, otherwise they might not see it.

Comment: okay @halfer ill do that [thumbsup]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably I think that's interpolation, wherein you can configure the interpolation markup. Defaults to {{ and }}. However I'm surprised to see this on `ng-model`.

[$interpolateProvider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/%24interpolateProvider)

```
angular.module('myApp',[]).config(function($interpolateProvider) {
  $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('//');
  $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('//');
});
```

Comment: i just found it within the code that it appears to be interpolated as said. var template = res.data.replace(/\$\$value\$\$/g,'model.'+(form.key || ""));
                  $compile(template)(scope,function(clone){
                    element.replaceWith(clone);
                  });

Comment: now confirmed that it was dynamically bind/interpolated from test in that way so i would be choosing this answer. thank you.

Comment: There is a big difference between some custom replacing logic and trying to use Angular's $interpolate as an expression for ng-model.

Comment: i see @tasseKATT,  thanks, so it wasn't 'interpolate' per se.

Answer (score 1):

the $$ are angulars private identifier and should not be accessed

https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05

i can only assume $$value$$ refers to a user created variable cause i have never seen that variable in a scope definition before, the usual are

```
$$childHead:
$$childTail: 
$$listeners: Object
$$nextSibling: Child
$$prevSibling: 
$$watchers: Array[]
```